# get response from a action in ruby on rails, using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
$.post("/students/fetch", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data){
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });
```

How can return "Any sample text from a action in ruby and rails.". I want to do something like:--

```
def fetch
  // do something... some processing... and finally
  return "any random string "  
end
```

So whole story should be something like:--

1. Send a post request.
2. return some string from the action.
3. alert that string which we got from that action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to return text from an action:

```
def fetch
  render :text => "any random string"
end
```

Comment: @piemesons , you can mark his answer ...if it fixed your problem